# PHP Automatically Inserting Data to Database Annoyance

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, insert

First time building a site and I want this "tracker page" (index.php) to be a HTML form where I submit my workout information. After submission I want the page to refresh and be ready for the next submission. My issue is that I have a login.php page and the **second** that it goes from login.php to my index.php it inserts a null row into the DB.

My recent solution attempts have been making it so that $excercisename cannot be null, but as a VARCHAR it submits as '' automatically into DB. I have tried in some of the comments fixing that but none worked :( Does anybody have any ideal solutions for solving this please? Didn't post HTML as I think this is PHP issue? But I am noob.

```
<?php

//Connect to database
include('database.php');

//grab user logged in for database insertion

   $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];

   $ses_sql = mysqli_query($dbcon,"select username from t_login where username = '$user_check' ");

   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

   $login_session = $row['username'];

// Create DB Variable
   $login_session = $row['username'];
//if(empty($_POST['exercisename'])) {return null;} ELSE {$_POST['excercisename'];}
//$excercisename = (empty($_POST['$excercisename']) ? $_POST['$excercisename'] : null);
   $excercisename = (isset($_POST['excercisename']) ? $_POST['excercisename'] : null);
   $setcount = (isset($_POST['setcount']) ? $_POST['setcount'] : null);
   $rep1 = (isset($_POST['rep1']) ? $_POST['rep1'] : null);
   $weight1 = (isset($_POST['number1']) ? $_POST['number1'] : null);
   $comments = (isset($_POST['comments']) ? $_POST['comments'] : null);

   $sql = "INSERT INTO t_workout (username, excercisename, setcount, set1reps, set1weight, comments) 
 VALUES ('$login_session', '$excercisename', '$setcount', '$rep1', '$weight1', '$comments')";

if ($dbcon->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Waiting for entry.";
    //echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $dbcon->error;
}
$dbcon->close();
?>
```

Comment: In your comments you tried `return`. You can't use that, if you're not inside a function. If you just want to end the script, you can use `exit` or `die`. But it normally isn't an ideal solution.

Comment: **Warning** Your code contains multiple SQL injection vulnerabilities. Switch to parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
if(isset($excercisename) and !empty($excercisename)){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO t_workout (username, excercisename, setcount, set1reps, set1weight, comments) 
    VALUES ('$login_session', '$excercisename', '$setcount', '$rep1', '$weight1', '$comments')
}
```

Be careful with security, I see that you are not using pdo or sql-li to prevent injection attacks, this is basic !!

Comment: You don't need both `isset` and `!empty`. `empty` checks if the variable is set.

Comment: Also, `$exercisename` is always set.